# Alter table to Change Column Name error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Here I tried to ALTER a table to change column name but an error happens.

```
Alter table [dbo].[Users] 
CHANGE
username UserName varchar(50),
password PassWord varchar(50),
state State int,
name Name varchar(50),
license License varchar(50),
lansno LansNo varchar(50) ,
curcuit_no CurcuitNo varchar(50) ,
communism Communism varchar(100) ,
Olduid OldUid int ,
Is_hunter Is_Hunter bit ,
free_text [FreeText] text ,
country Country varchar(50) ,
curcuit Curcuit varchar(50) ,
license_territory LicenseTerritory [varchar](50) ,
forest Forest varchar(50) ,
association Association varchar(50),
hunt_ar Hunt_Ar varchar(50) ,
area Area varchar(50) ,
contract Contract varchar(50) ,
radio_frequency RadioFrequency varchar(50)
)
```

This error happens:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near 'CHANGE'.

So.. I here I tried it to Alter table Change Old column name new column name datatype .. but here I receive the error

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx  .. alter table syntax

Comment: or this one. http://www.sqlexamples.info/SQL/tsql_alter_names.htm

Comment: The command is `ALTER TABLE ... ALTER COLUMN ... ` and allows you to change various properties like datatype etc. for an existing column. This **cannot** be used to change the column's name, however. Use `EXECUTE sp_rename ....` instead (see Nalaka's answer for details). All those SQL commands are [perfectly well documented at MSDN Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx) which is available to anyone, anywhere, for free - **use it!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
EXEC sp_RENAME 'Users.username', 'UserName', 'Column'
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a closer look at the Syntax

[ALTER TABLE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx)

If I am not mistaken it is `ALTER COLUMN`, not `CHANGE COLUMN`

Further more you should probably have a read here

[SQL SERVER – How to Rename a Column Name or Table Name](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/26/sql-server-how-to-rename-a-column-name-or-table-name/)

Comment: That allows you to change the e.g. datatype or `NULL vs. NOT NULL` properties of an existing column - you cannot however change the column name with `ALTER COLUMN...`

Comment: @marc_s That is why I added the second link/article